# Setting a session variable in a flyway postgres migration?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I am attempting to run the following sql command in a flyway postgres migration:

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.1;
```

After the migrations are run, querying this variable shows that it was never set to that value. Is there a way to fix thsi?